# Can't set Desktop Background on Mac with AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript, macos-catalina

I am trying to set the Desktop Wallpaper of my Mac(Running latest version of Catalina). But I keep getting this error message when trying to run my apple script.

> error "System Events got an error: Can’t set file \"Library:Desktop Pictures:Ink Cloud.jpg:\" of current desktop to file \"Library:Desktop Pictures:Ink Cloud.jpg:\" of current desktop." number -10006 from file "Library:Desktop Pictures:Ink Cloud.jpg:" of current desktop

here is my code

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell current desktop
        set picture rotation to 0
        set picture to file "Library:Desktop Pictures:Ink Cloud.jpg:"
    end tell
end tell
```

I've been able to change all the other properties of the Desktop except the actual photo. I also tried using / for the file path. I have tried different file paths. But still not luck. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: was this working in Mojave?

Comment: You're close but need a couple of changes (assuming nothing drastic has changed with Catalina). Preface the file specification with 'alias' instead of 'file'. Then remove the trailing colon. When it is the last character, it means that the last item must be a folder. And as vadian mentioned, the path should begin with the drive name, e.g. 'Macintosh HD'. So… alias "Macintosh HD:Library:Desktop Pictures:Foggy Forest.jpg". You could always run 'path to desktop pictures folder' to get the spec. Since you're using colons to to specify the path to the image, you should avoid using '/'.

Answer (score 0):

Running the code

```
tell application "System Events"
    set currentPicturePath to picture of current desktop
end tell
```

reveals that the path is supposed to be a (slash separated) POSIX path

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell current desktop
        set picture rotation to 0
        set picture to "/Library/Desktop Pictures/Ink Cloud.jpg"
    end tell
end tell
```

Your (colon separated) HFS path contains two mistakes:

- An HFS path (unlike the POSIX path) starts always with a disk name.
- Only references to folders and packages have a trailing colon.

Comment: I was wondering if there is a way to set this for every desktop? I used "every" instead of "current" but it doesn't seem to be working.

Steps:
1. Have more than 1 space
2. Change the wallpaper
3. It doesn't change for all desktops

Comment: `repeat with aDesktop in (get desktops)` `tell contents of aDesktop ...`

Comment: it seems like the wallpaper is changed only for one current space and all other current spaces still shows old wallpaper. 
here is the entire script https://codeshare.io/6pBDK0

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with scripting spaces.